# Is there a well-defined `uniform' distribution on $C([0, 1])$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm wondering whether we can define a uniform distribution on the space of continuous functions over a compact set, e.g. $C([0, 1])$. If so, then how should I rigorously describe it? And how can I numerically `draw' a random function from this distribution? If not, then what additional assumption/constraints should I impose to have a well-defined uniform or any kind of distribution that I can easily draw samples from?

Comment: Perhaps [Gaussian measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_measure) (see [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22probability+measure%22+%22Banach+space%22) also) are what you're looking for.

Comment: The most natural sense of "uniform" would be "translation invariant", analogous to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  But no such distribution exists: [there is no infinite-dimensional Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure).

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the reference here! If we cannot define uniform distribution on $C([0, 1])$, then what is the most natural way to define a probability distribution on it? And more importantly, how can we numerically draw samples, i.e., randomly choose functions in $C([0, 1])$, from this distribution?

Comment: @mw19930312: The most "natural" measure that people tend to consider is Wiener measure, the law of Brownian motion.  This is a huge topic in probability theory.  There are lots of ways to numerically approximate a Brownian motion, e.g. a random walk with small step size.  Wiener measure is in particular a Gaussian measure, as Dave L. Renfro suggested.